# How to initiate Edge (Chromium) browsing session using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am getting following error while running driver
Edge opens but then this error pops up and cant run rest of the code

**MY CODE**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jawad Azhar Ch\Documents\1.CODING\idm dload\id.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Edge()
  File "C:\Users\Jawad Azhar Ch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Jawad Azhar Ch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Jawad Azhar Ch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Jawad Azhar Ch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Jawad Azhar Ch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 208, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unknown error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation in [Use WebDriver (Chromium) for test automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python) to initiate a Microsoft Edge (Chromium) *Browsing Context* using [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) you need to follow the steps mentioned below:

- [Install Microsoft Edge (Chromium)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python#install-microsoft-edge-chromium): Ensure that you have installed [Microsoft Edge (Chromium)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). To confirm that you have Microsoft Edge (Chromium) installed, go to `edge://settings/help` in the browser, and verify the version number is **Version 75** or later.
- [Download Microsoft Edge Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python#download-microsoft-edge-driver): To begin automating tests, use the following steps to ensure that the WebDriver version you install matches your browser version.

  - Go to `edge://settings/help` to get the version of Edge.

[image: edge-version.png]

- Navigate to the [Microsoft Edge Driver downloads](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads) page and download the driver that matches the Edge version number.

[image: edge-driver-install.png]

---

### Demonstration

You can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\msedgedriver.exe')
  driver.get('edge://settings/help')
  print("Page title is: %s" %(driver.title))
  ```
- Console Outout:

  ```
  Page title is: Settings
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: MSEdge]

Comment: IT WORKED
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're importing everything required among some other issues, refer to this:
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/launch-edge-browser-in-selenium

Comment: Tried this Didnt work
my code does launch edge but then this error pops up